# How to remove section header separator in iOS 15

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit, ios15

In iOS 15, `UITableView` adds a separator between a section header and the first cell:

[image]

How can I hide or remove that separator?

A few notes:

1. The header is a custom view returned from `tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:)`.
2. When looking at the view debugger, I can see that the extra separator is actually a subview of the first cell, which now has a top and a bottom separator.
3. Other than setting `tableView.separatorInset` to change the inset of cell separators, this is a completely standard table view with no customizations.

Comment: it looks your tableView is grouped tableView

Comment: In iOS 15 plain style `UITableView` adds first row top separator even if you don't have a header. And it looks weird if you have `UINavigationBar` shadow because they overlap.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Option 1:
Maybe by using `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone` with the table view and replacing the system background view of the cell with a custom view which only features a bottom line?

Option 2: Using hint from https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/684706

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 150000 // only Xcode 13+ needs and can compile this
    if (@available(iOS 15.0, *)) {
        [self.tableview setSectionHeaderTopPadding:0.0f];
    }
#endif
}
```

Comment: Option 2 does work! I tried changing the value of `sectionHeaderTopPadding` but didn't set it to 0. Option 1 should also work, but I was trying to avoid managing the separators myself.

Comment: @user1561346 It is for me? Or do you mean the code in the thread is not working?

Comment: @user1561346 It looks like the link to the dev forum at Apple requires a login.

Comment: I found this issue (additional space on top of table views) seems to be an issue with Xcode 13 since it does not occur when building an app with Xcode 12.5.1 and running it on iOS 15. It happens for me only when building with Xcode 13.

Comment: Option 2 only works on plain style

Comment: Option 2 works on `.plain` style (I haven't tested this solution in other styles), and it also removes the separator below the last cell of the table.

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar issue, but it was due to the table header view suddenly showing as a separator on iOS 15. The only thing that worked for me was:

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *)
{
    tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView()
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**iOS 15, Swift 5**

To remove the line between the section header and your first cell, you should set sectionHeaderTopPadding to zero while configuring your UITableView.

```
    if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
        tableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0.0
    }
```

Comment: right solution for tableView header

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix it with this code.

```
if (@available(iOS 15.0, *)) {
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, CGFLOAT_MIN)];
    [self.tableView setSectionHeaderTopPadding:0.0f];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe `tableView.separatorStyle = .none` should do the trick.

Comment: Setting `separatorStyle` to `none` will remove the separator below *all* the cells of the table, looks like the OP wants to remove the separator *only* below the header, not below *all* the cells.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wanted to use the native section header and the top padding different than 0, so this should work if you want to remove the extra top and  bottom separators on each section:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Dequeue cell and set it up ...
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let separator = cell.subviews.filter({
            $0.frame.minY == 0 && $0 !== cell.contentView
        }).first
        separator?.isHidden = true
        cell.separatorInset.left = 0 // Or whatever desired inset
    }
    if indexPath.row + 1 == dataSource[indexPath.section].count {
        cell.separatorInset.left = cell.bounds.width
    } else {
        cell.separatorInset.left = 0 // Or whatever desired inset
    }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score -2):

There can be two solutions to your problem/

1. One is

   self.tableView.separatorColor = self.tableView.backgroundColor

this is a trick solution, it makes outer lines "disappear" and keep separator lines visible

2. second is

change your `tableview` type from grouped to plain if grouping not used.

Comment: The first solution will require that I manage separators manually since this will hide separators for all cells. Also, this table view is already using the plain style.

Comment: it will not hide all  just try that

Comment: I did try it and it does hide the separators for me. I'm guessing that our table views are configured a bit differently.